# Inline comments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, comments

Is Ruby able to understand in-line comments like:

```
my_array = ['first', /* 'second', */ 'third', 'fourth']
```

?

**Update:**

I asked not about what is /* */ in Ruby and why I receive an error, but about presence of in-line comments in any available form at all. /* */ were given only as example of in-line comments known to me.

Comment: This is why I love [Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/9nYmaxII)... :D

Comment: @texasbruce Your comment does not make sense. The OP is asking whether there is an inline comment in Ruby like `/* ... */`, not whether `/* ... */` is the exact syntax if such thing exists.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, Ruby does not have inline comments.

Comments of this style have a tendency to reduce readability, since they makes the code harder to follow.

In your case it would be best to split your array items into separate rows and comment out the one row.

```
my_array = ['first',
#           'second',
            'third',
            'fourth']
```

Comment: +1. Readability/maintenance suffer by doing an in-line comment.

Comment: I don't think Ruby will lose readability if there were one. You just have to have your text editor detect that and mark it up. If I were Matz, I think I would go along the lines of using the %-notation. For example, perhaps something like `%c{...}` may be a good candidate.

Comment: Sometimes inline comments can be very useful. Not as definitive code, where readability is affected, but to deactivate some part of the line code temporarily.

Comment: Oh.My.God. Really? Ruby is NOT the language which should be forcing not-to-use policy because it can influence readability loss. C'mon, Ruby has meta programming, crazy code constructions which can stump any, even experienced, developer. 

Ruby is the language in which you can do literally everything! Except inline comments. It's just crazy.

Comment: well you can use `sleep(10) # just tired` which is basically an inline comment no ?

Comment: "Comments of this style have a tendency to reduce readability, since they makes the code harder to follow." - Source?

Comment: @sawa I too would like `%c{...}`, and I would really expect it to nest properly, not like `/* ... */` in C for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that rdoc — Ruby's built-in documentation builder — can utilize the comments within your code to build an initial set of documentation. From what I've understood in my recent reading, the "Ruby way" suggests that your code should be readable and self-explanatory, but that comments are a valuable and simple way to build documentation in early development, before sending a project off to a proper documentation team.

On the subject of inline comments, my use-case is that I find myself working on longish one-liners in irb before committing them to my properly formatted source files. Perhaps many people don't mind working with line-breaks in their development environment, but with my limited knowledge of the toolset at the moment, I'm finding it tedious to repeat previous commands. I'm nearly certain this is due to my failure to grok the tools at hand, be it irb, pry and what-have-you. At the moment, I'm wrapping any code which I desire to comment inline inside of a string object, which I must later remove or "uncomment" by removing the string wrapper.

Take it or leave it, but those are my two cents! Keep on Rubying on!

*Addendum:*

It pays to read the `pry` doc! A `pry` method is bound to every object, including the `main`. Calling it executes a sub-shell in the current prompt that allows you to analyze any object within the current scope. It is available in any context, including the `main` pry prompt. Coupled with the the `amend-line`, `edit`, `hist`, `play` commands in Pry, this sates my desire for inline comments, although I'm still unaware of any feature in pry which will load a previous command into the current prompt's input for editing.

Invoking the text editor tends to distract me a fair bit, not only because it removes the contents of the shell buffer from visibility on a single display (e.g. laptop), but especially since it removes all of the helpful `pry` tab completions and commands. I'd like to see pry, or another REPL which enables use of the cursor across multiple lines, since I'm still finding the need to use one-liners.

Answer (score -3):

To be honest you shouldn't be using comments at all, your code should be self explanatory.

I know this may seems off topic but hear me out as a suggestion why they wont ever implement these kind of comments in Ruby.

I stumble upon this question because I'm processing our clients ugly API. The JSON request procesed to Ruby code looks something like this

```
api_response = {
  headers: ["uniq_id", "email", "description"]
  rows: [
    [2345, 'foo@bar.car', 'first item'],
    [9876, 'car@bar.foo', 'second item']
  ]
}
```

So in my script I want to collect all the uniq ids:

```
JSON.parse(api_response)
  .fetch('rows')
  .collect { |application_row| application_row.at(0) }
```

it would be nice to have some ability to comment what the `at(0)` is fetching. Like [sawa](/questions/13130859/inline-comments-in-ruby#comment-17859357) is suggesting in his comment, if `%c{}` would exist I could do something like this:

```
JSON.parse(api_response)
  .fetch('rows')
  .collect { |application_row|  %c{uniq_id}; application_row.at(0) }
```

...but then I realized I'm just being stupid. The self code should self explain my intention

```
uniq_ids = JSON.parse(api_response)
             .fetch('rows')
             .collect { |application_row| application_row.at(0) }
```

In some cases this is not an option, so maybe this would do the trick:

```
JSON.parse(api_response)
  .fetch('rows')
  .collect { |application_row| uniq_id = application_row.at(0) }
```

...yes this will lead to usage of unused local variable, however in this case this is ok as the readability of code would benefit not affecting performance too much.

in Pauls case he just want to remove one element from the Array. I guess he probably wants  it for debugging purpose, but the general idea is that Ruby force you to write you as clean code as possible and remove anything that won't be used in production.

solution for this could be

```
my_array =  ['first']
# my_array += ['second']
my_array += ['third', 'fourth']
```

Is this ugly ? well yes, that's the general thought is that you should re-factor this before you commit, enforcing you to remove ugly code and  remove unnecessary stuff along before hitting production.

---

**update 2019 05**

There are definitely cases where comment is needed. But proper reaction of developer should be: "oh my god there is a comment ! I need to  pay attention!"

I'm currently 12 year of professional experience in the field. And seen this over and over in projects: If there is a comment all over the code  developers will stop seeing comments as valuable information and just not read them.

But in principle there is no single use case of "let's place a comment here" that cannot be solved with a good code/architecture design :)

Just to quote [Martin Fowler](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler):

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.

Comment: *you shouldn't use comments at all*  That's insane.  You shouldn't use stupid or redundant comments. You should write code with good names, cleanly and well structured; I'll agree with trying to make code "readable".  But code is low level implementation detail of some higher level vision.  Until "code" can express both implementation and intent, you will forever need comments to write down intent (and even background behind the clever tricks in your code).

Comment: cannot agree more that best comment is the comment never wrote.  Code should explicitly tell intention. That being said, this answer of mine is for situations where developer is not able to do that. Imagine you work with legacy code, you need to submit quick change, and there is no time to refactor to properly decomposed objects.

Comment: The code *cannot tell/express intention*.  It can only tell implementation.  Regardless of how much of a hurry you are in (esp. if you are in a hurry), a well written-comment can guide the reader in ways the code cannot.

Comment: problem with comments is that they go out of date easily and then comments are a lie. Code **can tell/ express intention**  as long as developer is not writing it in structural programming fashion .  Ruby, **when used properly**, is beautiful language that can well express all that programmer would normally put to comment without writing a comment. If someone has 1000 line Controller then he has nothing to do with object oriented practices (even if used Ruby) and than yes he need comments.

Comment: Comments going out of date isn't a problem with comments; its a problem with the coders.   Assign the blame where it belongs.

Comment: yep, same discipline argument applies on coders urge to write the comments :) .If they structure the code properly there is no need for comment.

Comment: I guess we reach a point where both of us agree we disagree. I will add only one more reference to my arguments -  [Robert C. Martin - Clean coder series.  ep 5](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-5/show)  He pretty much summarize all I want to say. I know it's $20 but I guess that's the only way I can show you what I mean without spending hours of pointless discussion of repeating same arguments.

Comment: Yep, we're going to agree to disagree.  I admire Martin, but that's different than I believe everything he says.   I have a lot of experience of my own, and a unique perspective based on build large-scale program transformation tools and have a very technical understanding of the difference between intent and implementation.   Code *is* implementation.  It is *not* intent.  So where do you get intent from?  End of discussion.

Comment: b.t.w.;  one thing that I've just remembered. One place where I think comments have value is in Tests to describe problematic scenarios (both in Unit or Integration). So if I have a scenario where I need to write a comment I write it in a test. HOWEVER 98% of cases the RSpec "describe" "context" and "it" is enough to describe what is happening and why. I don't necessaries see the need in tools like  Cucumber, Spinach (or any other Gerkin lang tool) unless the team is too junior. So Tests are the real Code documentation   not comments.

Comment: I use comments to document "unusual" aspects of external dependencies (e.g. a REST call, uploaded CSV files, interacting with a service that actually defies its advertised documentation...) that CANNOT be discerned just by reading this app's code. To stop a future dev (usually myself) from saying..."That's dumb...lemme fix that janky code!" ...only to break the app. Possibly in some odd scenario that won't happens for MONTHS after the "code improvement".